# Python & pandas: how to group in a nonstandard way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know basic pandas functions, but I'm not clear how to group in this case.

I have a dataframe with a list of various fruits and their characteristics:

```
fruit    x1      x2
apple    red     sweet
apple    yellow  sweet
apple    green   tart
apple    red     sweet
apple    red     sweet
```

How could I sum each fruit (there are more after apples) like this?

3 apples:   red and sweet
1 apple:    yellow and sweet
1 apple:    green and tart

I've looked at groupby, tried an apply function, and looked over pandas documentation, but this escapes me.

Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Comment: df.groupby(['x1','x2','fruit']).size()

Comment: Heeeeeyyyyyy thanks Wen!!! Now that I look again, I see size() on this page, but it's easy to overlook.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `Counter`

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

pd.Series(Counter(map(tuple, df.values)))

apple  green   tart     1
       red     sweet    3
       yellow  sweet    1
dtype: int64
```

---

### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
i, r = pd.factorize(list(map(tuple, df.values)))
pd.Series(dict(zip(r, np.bincount(i))))

apple  green   tart     1
       red     sweet    3
       yellow  sweet    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
df['count']=0
group_df = df.groupby(["fruit","x1","x2"])['count'].count().reset_index()
```

The output will be as below:

```
   fruit      x1     x2  count
0  apple   green   tart      1
1  apple     red  sweet      3
2  apple  yellow  sweet      1
```

of course, you can concatenate columns after this to make it exactly as your required output.

And if u want the count to be sorted :

```
group_df = df.groupby(["fruit","x1","x2"])['count'].count().reset_index().sort_values(by=['count'],ascending=False)
```